# How can I find where is a help message in the component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, email, aura, html, type

There is a field 'Email' that has a validation message in case of invalid inputs when it loses focus (like in the picture, for example).
I have to know the rule of this message, but I can't find where is it in the developer console and searching in VsCode.
What I know is when I change `type = "email"` to `type = "text"`, the message is not displayed. Where could I see this message code?

[image]

P.s: there isn't a onblur event (see the code below).

See the part of the code:

```
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" id="client-data" >
        <div class="slds-col" >
            <div class="slds-grid_vertical">
                <div class="title-transfer-block"><p id="title-transferencia">Personal Email</p></div>
                    
                    <div class="margin-top-10" id="email">
                        <label for="clientEmail">Email</label>
                        <lightning:input name="clientEmail"
                                         type="email"
                                         aura:id="clientEmail"
                                         required="false" 
                                         value="{!v.clientEmail}"
                                         label="Email" 
                                         variant="label-hidden"
                                         maxlength="60"/>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's provided by the platform automatically. However, the [OSS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components) version should have the exact same message, so you might want to take a look at it.